# Microsoft Word - Not all Pages being displayed

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, sharepoint-2013

I'm working on a report with some colleagues using Microsoft Word and Sharepoint.

It was working OK until a few hours ago, but now there are some problems:

If I open the document in word online, I can view all 35 pages of the document.

If I try to edit the document in Microsoft Word, however, I can only view the first 2 pages of the document, but the word count at the bottom is for 5642 words (which would correspond to 35 pages). For some reason at the bottom it says I'm on "Page 2 of 3," but I cannot see anything beyond 2.

I tried Selecting all and copying (Using Ctrl+A and then Ctrl+C) and pasting to a new Word document. If I paste selecting using "the destination theme" or "merging formatting," all 35 pages come through. However, if I paste using the option of "Keeping Source Formatting", the same problem comes up (only 2 pages visible).

I unfortunately need to keep the original formatting as this is a company report.

Any assistance so that I can view and edit the whole document with the original formatting would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked for [hidden text](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/ms-office-tips/word-hidden-text/)?

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly David. I just did, and makes no difference - still 3 pages!

Comment: Have you checked if the text foreground and background colour are the same?

Comment: They're different to my understanding. However, if I select all and click the button to "Remove all formatting", then everything is visible.

Comment: *shrug* It's something in your formatting then :)

Comment: Oh well - can't figure out what that is. Got someone to email me the document, and can read it all, will have to re-upload when done. However, any other ideas much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post but I just managed to resolve it for a user who had problems on her system.  The problem was relating to track changes on the word document.  As soon as we removed all the markup info (under the review tab), she could see all the pages

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, where I was able to view only the first two pages of the document, out of the 13 pages.

It turned out to be a result of incompatible Microsoft Office versions. The document was originally created on Microsoft Word (Microsoft office for mac version 16.10), and I was trying to edit it in version 15.1.

Updating my Microsoft office to the latest one (version 16.10) resolved the issue, and I was able to view all the pages in the document.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of research, I figured it out on my own. I know this is a very old question but very useful as future reference.

Look for the "style definition" balloon text, right-click it, and choose "reject change."

You're welcome.